# Read lines of file and assign to threads

Tags: c, multithreading, fgets

I have a file and want to read each line and pass it to a thread. However what I have currently written does not work properly,since threads created don't seem to have a different line each,which is kind of buffling. Here is the code

```
void *threadfunction(void* r){
    char* command;
    command=(char*) r;
    printf("%s\n",command);
}

//main here
int count=0;
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)!=NULL){
        int retval=0;
        retval=pthread_create(&tthread[count],NULL,threadfunction,(void*)line);
        count++;
}
```

I would expect it reads the line, then send it to newly created thread and repeat. But I guess im wrong.

Comment: You should try to build a true [mcve] so that we can reproduce with your exact code. What is written here look correct except that the `printf` command in the thread function is not synchronized (only one thread should try to print at the same time).

Comment: Well @SergeBallesta it seems that was the problem... Adding just a sleep(1) in the loop produces correct output. I just wanted to check that threads get right arguments anyway, and now i am sure. I don't really understand the "build a true mre" though, I thought I described my problem well enough. Advice on what more I should include in future questions? Ty

Comment: A [mcve] should contain enough code (and if needed input data) for others to reproduce. Here, I need a true `main` including the declaration of `tthread`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a *struct* to pass arguments to threads (specially pointers)

Example :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

typedef struct{ // our custom struct

    int id; // an id index
    char *message; // our message - line to print

}ARG; // define it as "ARG"

void threadFun(void *p){ // our function that the threads will start from

     ARG *arguments = (ARG *) p; // pass the pointer p to the "arguments" pointer (that we have set that it points to a ARG struct)

     //printf("Test\n");
     // fflush(stdout);
     printf("Hello, here is thread %d, my message is [%s]\n", arguments->id, arguments->message);
     fflush(stdout);
     free(arguments->message); // free our pointer

     pthread_exit(0); // try removing this <------

     asm("push 0xdead"); // if something goes wrong, crush the program
     asm("ret");
}

int main(void){

     ARG *temp =(ARG *) malloc(sizeof(int) + sizeof(char *)); // create a temporary arguments struct

     char *filename = (char *) malloc(1000); // allocating 1000 bytes to store our filename

     printf("Enter a file to read : ");

     fgets(filename, 1000, stdin); // read up to 1000 chars (from stdin)

     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) // clear the \n from the input string
         if(filename[i] == '\n')
             filename[i] = 0;

     FILE * input = fopen(filename , "r"); // open to read the file

     int count = 0, i = 0; // count : count the bytes we need to allocate, i is an index to count where we are on the message pointer
     int lastcursor = 0; // lastcursor : remainder of where our line start
     char ch = 0; // a temporary byte to store our input (from the file)

     temp->id = 0; // start from id = 0

     pthread_t threads[10000]; // allocating 10000 spaces to store our threads

     while(ch != EOF){ // read until we reach the End-Of-File

        while(ch != '\n'){ // Read the line
            ch = fgetc(input);
            count++; // count the line's length
        }

        temp->message = (char *) malloc (count-1); // allocate count-1 bytes to store our line (but not the \n) - will be freed in consumer thread
        fseek(input, lastcursor, 0); // go back to the start of the line
        lastcursor += count; // remember the end of the line
        ch = 1; // delete the \n character from our temp. byte
        count = 0; // set count to 0

        while(ch != '\n'){
            ch = fgetc(input); // read from the file
            if(ch != '\n') // if our input != \n
                 temp->message[i] = (char) ch; // store it to temp->message(pointer) + i(offset)
            i++; // increase our index
        }
        i = 0; // zero our index
        ch = 1; // delete the \n

        printf("Creating thread %d\n", temp->id);
        fflush(stdout); // flush the output

        pthread_create(&threads[temp->id], NULL, &threadFun,(void *) temp); // creating the thread

        printf("Created thread %d\n", temp->id);
        fflush(stdout);

        for(int i = 0; i < 0xffffff; i++){;} // small delay

        ch = fgetc(input); // check if the next char is EOF (by reading the next char and storing it to ch - so the while loop will check if ch == EOF - and in the next line go our cursor back by 1 character)
        fseek(input, lastcursor, 0); // set our cursor to the end of the line

        //  printf("Cursor at %d\n", lastcursor);

        temp->id++; // increase the id index
    }

    return temp->id-2; // return the number of USEFULL threads (not the NULL)
}
```